# PhpUnit Artisan:call explode expects parameter 2 to be string

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to test a **Laravel 5.1** controller with PhpUnit, for that im creating a class inheriting from **TestCase**, and using **DatabaseTransactions** and **WithoutMiddleware** traits.

Within the class im implementing the **setUpBeforeClass** method which contains:

```
Artisan::call('migrate:refresh');
```

When i try to run the test I get the following error:

```
1) JugadoresControllerTest::test_Index_trae_arreglo_de_jugadores
ErrorException: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/illuminate/support/helpers.php:390
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php:319
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:428
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:1548
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php:53
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:79
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:74
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:503
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:150
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:259
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:136
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php:62
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:152
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:210
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/tests/unit/JugadoresControllerTest.php:34
/home/vagrant/Code/marcadores/tests/unit/JugadoresControllerTest.php:34
/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:151
/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:103
```

Hope anyone can helpme!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you ever figured this out, but I ran into a similar problem when trying to run phpunit tests under laravel 5.1.  Apparently I had some out-of-date vendor builds on my global composer install (as reverenced by your error: `/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/illuminate/support/helpers.php:390`)

All I did was cd to my composer directory:
`cd /home/vagrant/.composer` and ran `composer update`

This updated my global composer and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks man, in my case I restarted homestead and everythings worked fine. Forgot to post xD

Comment: Thanks! Just resolved this error with your suggestion.